# why data not showing up with $http.get in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a connection with a database using `angularJS`. I'm using `$http.get` for connecting with a PHP server

**controller**

```
var oke = angular.module('secondApp',[]);
          oke.controller('dataAdmin',function(){
            return{
              controller : function($scope,$http){
                $scope.displayData = function(){
                $http.get('db.php').success(function(hasil){
                  $scope.datas=hasil;

                });
                console.log($scope.datas);
                }
              }
            };
          });
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="dataAdmin" ng-init="displayData()" ng-app="secondApp">
      <input type="text" ng-model="hasil" placeholder="Search" style="margin-left:2%;margin-bottom:5px;"/>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="nt in datas | filter:hasil | orderBy:'username'">
            Username : {{nt.username}} | Password : {{nt.password}}
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: what are you getting in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller code needs a few changes:

```
  var oke = angular.module('secondApp',[]);
  oke.controller('dataAdmin', ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶{̶
     ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶{̶
      ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶ ̶:̶ function($scope,$http){
        $scope.displayData = function(){
          $http.get('db.php'). ̶s̶u̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶ then(function(hasil){
            $scope.datas= ̶h̶a̶s̶i̶l̶;̶ hasil.data;
            console.log($scope.datas);
          });
         ̶c̶o̶n̶s̶o̶l̶e̶.̶l̶o̶g̶(̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶s̶)̶;̶
        };
       ̶}̶
     ̶}̶;̶
  });
```

The `console.log` needs to be inside the `.then` method.

Answer (score 0):

Access the data of your response

```
$http.get('db.php').then(function(hasil){
  $scope.datas=hasil.data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$http.get('db.php').then(function(result){
   $scope.datas = result.data;
}, function(err){
   console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log($scope.datas)` will display undefined, as it will run before getting response,

write this code in your success Call Back. and it will display value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the **data** which you are getting inside the response.

$scope.datas=hasil.data;